# Customize package compilation option R

Tags: r, compiler-construction, cran

I'm building a package containing an old *f77* code that should absolutely be build with the `o0` optimization option.

In the `/src/Makevars` of my package I added this line:

```
FFLAGS=-O0 -pipe  -g $(LTO)
```

but when I compile my package, I see R is still using
the default compiling options from the `/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf` file:

```
gfortran   -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Babar.f -o Babar.o
```

How can I override the default compilation options for the FORTRAN files of my package in R?

(I intend to distribute that package through CRAN so the compilation option should be set from the *Makevars* file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the best solution I found for this is to do it as is done in the quadprog package (ver 1.5-5). Here is what the relevant parts of the src/Makevars file look like:

```
mypackage_FFLAGS = $(FPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_FFLAGS) 
all: $(SHLIB)
Babar.o: Babar.f
    $(F77) $(mypackage_FFLAGS) -O1 -pipe -g -c -o Babar.o Babar.f
```

So, for example when you send the package to the [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx) here is what the compiler output looks like (confirming that this solution does indeed work):

```
gfortran     -O1 -pipe -g -c -o Babar.o Babar.f
```

Comment: If the options you give are not colliding, another possible solution It seems to set `FC=gfortran -O0 -pipe  -g ` in the `Makevars` file. In my case it showed up the options along the compiler. The drawback is that you will have also the standard ones afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

There are two to three things here:

1. As you note, R itself uses the options encoded from *its* run of `configure`, ie built-time. See the file `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`
2. You can override things via `src/Makevars` on a per-package basis. That is what you probably want here.  See R's `Makeconf` for the list of variables, and set eg `FFLAGS`.
3. You can override things for all your builds via a per-user `~/.R/Makevars`. Eg I set optimization and warning level for my builds in that file.

See the "Writing R Extensions" manual for details.

**Edit:**  And there is 1.a) You can edit a local file `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf.site` too. On Debian/Ubuntu, I softlink the directory `$RHOME/etc/` into `/etc/R` which makes that easier too.

Comment: Is this `Makeconf`, or `Makevars`? On https://cran.r-project.org und os x tools section at the minute, it refers to "create ~/.R/Makevars" with contents 

`CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
`

Comment: Yes, sorrym in 3. it is `~/.R/Makevars`.  Will correct.

Comment: Is it also `$RHOME/etc/Makevars.site`? I couldn't get `Makeconf.site` to work, but found a `Makevars.site` from here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Customizing-package-compilation

Comment: Do you have any advice here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69357390/695132 In that question, I am asking why point 3. from the above answer no longer seems to work.