# How to override compilers used by R?

Tags: r, path, r-package

When I try to compile R packages from source, it uses the compilers and settings defined in `etc/Makeconf` within the R installation directory. How can I override these settings?

I have an `~/.R/Makevars` file (suggested e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22479811/695132)), and I included the settings I want there, but these are not being used for some reason. Why not, and how can I fix this?

I could not find the official documentation on `~/.R/Makevars` and `Makeconf`—links would be welcome.

In the past, this very same setup used to work correctly for me, but recently it doesn't. I assume something must have changed in recent R versions, but I am not sure when. Were there any recent changes that could have affected this?

---

Motivation and context:

I am on macOS and I want to use `gfortran` from MacPorts. Thus I set `FC = /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-11` and `FLIBS = -L/opt/local/lib/gcc11 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm` in `~/.R/Makevars`. However, the system still wants to use a gfortran installation in `/usr/local`, which does not exist on my machine. It clearly takes the paths and options from `etc/Makeconf`. I am using the official R binaries.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the link. I have seen that question. The answer says that `~/.R/Makevars` _should_ override `Makeconf`, but on my machine it does not. My question is: why does is not, and how can I fix it? I suspect something must have changed in R in the past year and a half or so because before then everything worked correctly, and I do not recall making any relevant changed on my machine (other than updating R).

Comment: You will need to rebuild R from source with the alternate compilers.  Then `etc/Makeconf` will contain information about the compilers you used.  If you don't do this, you'll likely run into problems from differences between the assumptions made by the different compilers.  You might be able to get it to work, but you'll never be sure.

Comment: @user2554330 R has a C API. The C ABI is clearly defined on macOS. I do not see any issue. Either way, what I want to know is: (1) How to override values from `etc/Makeconf`? (2) Where this is documented? (3) Why overriding it with `~/.R/Makevars` no longer works when it used to work before. Do others see the same problem?

Comment: @Szabolcs: We doubt that. R expands these variables, it will read `~/.R/Makevars` and applies it.  Lots of people, R Core included, rely on this to finetune builds. You will have to demonstratet how/why it doesn't work.  _Ex ante_ the issue is local to you.  Maybe `$HOME` or `$USER` got messed up or something related.

Comment: @Szabolcs  The `~/.R/Makeconf` may best be though about as _altering_ but not replacing the default settings.  I am not a mac user but I believe the recommendation from mac.r-project.org is to use their toolchain.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the feedback. Is there any _simple_ way to check what values these variables would get without having an actual package and trying to compile it, then looking at the output? If there is, that would make it much easier for me to try to figure out what's going on. If there isn't, please still let me know so I don't waste time searching for it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2021-September/014191.html, written by the R Core member who is responsible for the R build you say you are using.  It's about changing C and C++ compilers, but other messages suggest Fortran also needs to match.

Comment: On macOS, it is not reasonable to try to use the gfortran distribution recommended on mac.r-project.org. It is intrusive, tries to overtake /usr/local, and interferes with other systems.

Comment: So no you created a _non-standard setup_ and are wondering why it is not behaving like a standard setup.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't understand what you are saying. It is a standard setup that does not respect `~/.R/Makevars`. The question was why. No one has touched on this question so far. Why do you downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason why `~/.R/Makevars` was ignored on my machine when trying to build a certain package was a bug in `withr`:

- https://github.com/r-lib/withr/issues/169

Installing the development version of `withr` using `devtools::install_github("r-lib/withr@master")` fixed the problem.